# jquery nested ajax success callback not working

Tags: jquery

```
function getByName(name) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'getprogress',
            dataType: "json",
            data: "name=" + name,
            success: function(data){
                updateProgress(data, name);
        }
        });     
}

function updateProgress(data, name){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'getdesc',
            dataType: "json",
            data: "name=" + name,
            success: function(data){
                alert('asdf');
                    }
        });
}
```

Unable to execute success callback of second ajax request. second ajax call is executed successfully. Server returns correct response But success callback is not getting executed.
Please help..

Comment: Any error on console?

Comment: You're not passing the `name` argument to the second function. Open up the page in Chrome and check the `Network` tab to see if the request is going  through.

Answer (score 0):

where is "name" in this function.?

```
function updateProgress(data){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'getdesc',
            dataType: "json",
            data: "name=" + name,
            success: function(data){
                alert('asdf');
                    }
        });
}
```

add "name" in your function parameter.

```
function updateProgress(data,name){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'getdesc',
            dataType: "json",
            data: "name=" + name,
            success: function(data){
                alert('asdf');
                    }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `.done()` and be careful at the signature of your function `(data,name)` vs `(data)`

```
jQuery.ajax({
url:"/Home/Index"+name,
data:JSON.stringify(data),
success:function(data){
      console.log("Some info");
     }
}).done(function(data,name){
    updateProgress(data,name);
})
```